# Laravel Validator removing null fields from array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm writing a test case to simulate a creation of a product. When creating the product, I'm passing an array of formats, and for some reasons, when validating with the controller, the `thumbnail` key is missing from the data.

This is the data I'm sending:

```
"formats" => array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "upc" => "584979099857"
    "vcode" => "VX43V14FN910479274209"
    "thumbnail" => null
  ]
]
```

And I send it like the following in my test case:

```
$response = $this->post(route('products.store'), $product);
```

For some reasons, when sending the request, the `thumbnail => null` disappears from the formats attribute.

Therefore, when validating the request, I always get the error that the thumbnail has to be present.

```
request()->validate([
    'formats' => 'bail|required|array',
    'formats.*.upc' => 'bail|required|string|max:255',
    'formats.*.vcode' => 'bail|required|string|max:255',
    'formats.*.thumbnail' => 'bail|present|image'
]);
```

I've also tried changing the rules of thumbnail to:

```
bail|required|nullable|image
```

Or

```
bail|nullable|required|image
```

But then I get the required error.

Does anyone know why the `thumbnail` key is getting removed from the `formats` array upon sending the request?

Comment: If thumbnail could be null, but must be present in array, try `bail|nullable|present|image`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte It doesn't change anything, I get the present error because it's not present.

Comment: Just `present` should work here, same with just `nullable`.  You can't combine required and nullable.

Comment: @Devon required with nullable gives the same as present. However, my field is no longer present and that's my problem.

Comment: I've just tested @FelippeDuarte suggestion and it works as expected, it successfully validates the request.